# using pgf backend to matplotlib in julia

Tags: matplotlib, julia, pgf

I started using Julia to analyse some data, which works perfect.

I also use PyPlot / Matplotlib for plotting, which I got working as well.

Now, these plots need to find their way into my latex document, which I want to achieve using the matplotlib pgf backend. It also works, but I really have no idea how to pass arguments to

```
mpl.rcParams.update(parameters)
```

Is there somebody skilled out there in the Julia community who can tell me how to achieve this?

---

EDIT2:

short update on the issue: Setting rc-options work by setting them in the following way:

```
PyPlot.matplotlib[:rc]("text", usetex=true) # here: allow tex rendering
```

Comment: How did you manage to use the pgf backend in Julia?

Comment: Setting the rc options for text.usetex is okay for a quick fix, but it's not actually using matplotlib's pgf backend. I also haven't been able to change the fonts going that route. I tried doing `PyPlot.matplotlib[:use]("pgf")` which runs but doesn't seem to do anything.